# PHP 7.4 PCRE2 newline character warning

Tags: php, regex

Been testing a codebase migration from 7.3 to 7.4, and the only thing that affected us is the PCRE update under PHP.

Currently this regex:
`/(\>)([\R\s\v\h]*)((\&|\#)?nbsp\;|(\&|\#)nbsp)*([\R\s\v\h]*)(\<)/`
Throws a nasty warning:
`Compilation failed: escape sequence is invalid in character class at offset 7`

And indeed, if I remove the \R, the warning disappears, but of course the behaviour changes.

I have read the PCRE2 syntax manual, and they list \R as a valid newline sequence character type ([see it here](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC4)). What's up with it then? Why does it throw a warning for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a character class, you can only define *single char matching patterns*. That means, `m` will denote `m` inside `[m]`, `\n` will denote an LF symbol in `[\n]`, `$` will match a `$` if it is in `[$]`.

The `\R` is not a single char matching pattern, it is roughly a `\u{000D}\u{000A}|[\u{000A}\u{000B}\u{000C}\u{000D}\u{0085}\u{2028}\u{2029}]` pattern that can match two chars, CR+LF.

Hence, you cannot use it in the character class. Use the chars separately, `\u{000A}\u{000B}\u{000C}\u{000D}\u{0085}\u{2028}\u{2029}` or, depending on the string literal type you use, `\x{000A}\x{000B}\x{000C}\x{000D}\x{0085}\x{2028}\x{2029}`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the ready-to-use replacement. Weird choice to remove such functionality from PCRE, but I guess its for the better.